# Python: compare an array element-wise with a float

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, logical-operators

I have an array `A=[A0,A1]`, where `A0 is a 4x3 matrix, A1 is a 3x2 matrix`. I want to compare A with a float, say, 1.0, element-wise. The expected return `B=(A>1.0)` is an array with the same size as A. How to achieve this?

I can copy A to C and then reset all elements in C to be 1.0, then do a comparison, but I think python (numpy/scipy) must have a smarter way to do this...
Thanks.

Comment: Your `A`, having a dtype of object, is little more than a list of arrays.  Most of the numpy power is in working with multidimensional arrays of numbers.

Comment: Some operations, like basic math ones, do 'pass through' to the inner arrays.  I don't know if there's a list of what works and what doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have the same shape of a array of arrays you mention:

```
>>> A=np.array([np.random.random((4,3)), np.random.random((3,2))])
>>> A
array([ array([[ 0.20621572,  0.83799579,  0.11064094],
       [ 0.43473089,  0.68767982,  0.36339786],
       [ 0.91399729,  0.1408565 ,  0.76830952],
       [ 0.17096626,  0.49473758,  0.158627  ]]),
       array([[ 0.95823229,  0.75178047],
       [ 0.25873872,  0.67465796],
       [ 0.83685788,  0.21377079]])], dtype=object)
```

We can test each elements with a where clause:

```
>>> A[0]>.2
array([[ True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

But not the whole thing:

```
>>> A>.2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

So just rebuild the array B thus:

```
>>> B=np.array([a>.2 for a in A])
>>> B
array([ array([[ True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False]], dtype=bool),
       array([[ True,  True],
       [ True,  True],
       [ True,  True]], dtype=bool)], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using List Comprehensions for 1 matrix

```
def compare(matrix,flo):
    return  [[x>flo for x in y] for y in matrix]
```

Assuming I understood your question correctly and for example

```
matrix= [[0,1],[2,3]]
print(compare(matrix,1.5))
```

should print `[[False, False], [True, True]]`

For a list of matrices:

```
def compareList(listofmatrices,flo):
    return [[[x>flo for x in y] for y in matrix] for matrix in listofmatrices]
```

or

```
def compareList(listofmatrices,flo):
    return [compare(matrix,flo) for matrix in listofmatrices]
```

UPDATE: recursive function:

```
def compareList(listofmatrices,flo):
    if(isinstance(listofmatrices, (int, float))):
        return listofmatrices > flo
    return [compareList(matrix,flo) for matrix in listofmatrices]
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, 3 for-loops definitely will work. But I wonder if python/numpy has some built-in features to perform comparison of a tensor with a scalar element-wise? What I mean is if later I have a rank 100 tensor, for example, the handcrafted code will be cumbersome (100 for-loops, certainly don't want that...)

Comment: @Void you can do that recursivly.